# add labels inside canvas context in dygraphs

Tags: javascript, canvas, dygraphs

Instead of having x and y labels outside the canvas as html elements I want to add them to the canvas. I try to do this by adding the required code for drawing the label into the canvas to the drawcallback. This aint an effective solution cause this fn doesnt get called all the time say when a point is highlighted. the axis labels that I custom added  then disappear. Also tried adding label drawing code to the highlightcallback and unhighlight callback but this doesn't seem elegant.  I also want to add some more details into the canvas as and when needed. How do I do that in the most elegant way ?